# Azure Search Service went into "Provisioning" mode (but nothing was changed) Search Index was down

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Hello Azure search team - 
                  We are having a bizarre situation with our azure search service. Our service in production went in to "Provisioning" mode although nobody changed anything for the service. We are not sure why this happened. The result of that was that our index was down for at least 30 mins and was throwing errors.

In what event/scenario can this happen? We are very concerned about this kind of behavior in the future Please advise!

P.S. I can provide you with more info as needed.

Thanks!

Comment: I was digging into this more and i found these error messages on the indexers:
 They have a history of 50 failed events, that go back to about 2:30 this morning.  The message says:
> Indexer execution is deferred because the service is being updated. The indexer will resume automatically according to its schedule. To allow indexers to run during service updates, the service must have at least 3 replicas.

Comment: Does this mean we always have to have 3 replicas and if we have less than that the service can go into "Provisioning" mode and index/indexers can be affected?

Please advise.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Search services can go into "Provisioning" status when the service is being updated. To achieve [high availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-capacity-planning#high-availability) for reads (index queries), at least 2 replicas are required. For write (indexer and index update/delete) high availability you need at least 3 replicas.

If you have 3 replicas, the service will be updated 1 replica at a time, so you can perform read/writes even when it is being updated.

If you have 2 replicas, the service will be able to serve index query requests when one of the replicas is being updated, but not index updates/deletes.